# Groovy script not running

Tags: java, netbeans, groovy

I am using Netbeans 7.4. I have created a new web project using glassfish server. Now I like to use a groovy script into it. But the problem is groovy code is not interpreting there. Its giving output same as the code.

```
def name='Barun' 
println "Hello $name!"
```

It should give output **Hello Barun!** but instead of that giving me output **def name='Barun' println "Hello $name!"**

I have also included the latest groovy-all jar file into my project library. But no luck yet. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: How are you running the script?

Comment: @tim_yates - 
1) I created a new java web project from Netbeans 7.4. 
2) Then Right click and add a new Groovy Script file. And drag-drop it into same folder as index.jsp.
3) Added the groovy library from project property.
4) Now index.jsp is running fine. But when I am calling abc.groovy its sending coded page not interpreted page.

Comment: So you've set up a servlet or something to interpret *.groovy files?

Comment: @tim_yates - Sorry I am new to groovy. Netbeans 7.4 is not giving me web.xml file. Please tell me how to setup the servlet ??

Answer (score 0):

This is a very dirty solution. I dont even know if it is the perfect solution or not. What I did when creating the new project I used jre 5 instead of 7, So that I got the web.xml file there. Now I can modify the web.xml to add these lines

```
<servlet>
<servlet-name>Groovy</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>groovy.servlet.GroovyServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>Groovy</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>*.groovy</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

And now my groovy script is working.